# Any way to tell if user has disabled Notification "peeking"?

Tags: android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

There's a new option in Android 6.0 that lets users disable notification Peeking, is there a way to tell whether peeking is enabled or disabled for my app?

Comment: have you found some work around for this?

Comment: no unfortunately not